# Does the question need to edited or did I miss a rule?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

[How to correctly identify an actor/actresses is in something that is not listed on their IMDB profile?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1689/how-to-make-sure-an-actor-actresses-is-in-something-that-is-not-on-their-imdb-pr#comment2541_1689)

I'm not asking to edit IMDB. I'm asking how to verify if it's not listed. From previous answers given on this site from contributors I assume that IMDB and wiki are used often and are credible sources. So basically why was my question closed?

Comment: I've reopened it to see if this can gain any more traction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting question, and one that I have some understanding of.

IMDb credits are generated by the filmmakers (for example, whenever I submit a new short to festivals, I create an IMDb page for it, then start to fill in the cast and crew credits). On occasion crew members get left off the submission form - it has also happened to me, I appear as three different entities on IMDb because the filmmakers I was working for neglected to see if I was already represented and created a new page for me.
This is certainly the case with other actors/crew members, and could go some way to explaining the discrepancies.

Based on the evidence of this answer in meta, does it fit into the M&TV SE site?

I'm leaning towards yes - but I'll bow to those of you who know better :)

Comment: It's the community's site.  We only step in when there can't be a decision made a la the TV discussion :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an odd question.  The best way to go about answering something about this, to me, is to use screenshots of movie credits/of the performer in the piece.

I honestly think its a good question though, I can see @DForck42's hesitation at the question as I had the same hesitation.  But after re-reading it, it made more sense to me and I figured if it didn't, then people would flag, and I would review it further.

That said, if it gets any reopen votes, I wouldn't mind doing so and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I misunderstood what you are trying to ask.  So, to rephrase this, are you wanting another place/reference to double check and see if an actor/actoress is in a piece of work?  IE, cross-referencing IMDB with Wikipedia?

Comment: No not really cross checking with wiki since I could look on there or even sign up to alter it, but I would want to verify whether the information I enter is correct. Since these are the basic sources I'm not really looking for a list of other sites to check but rather how just how to make sure the actor/actress was in something. I can try to clarify the question.

Comment: I edited the question to try to clarify what I am asking could you take another look and see if it can be reopened?